# Redirecting www directory to non www https directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

The code below redirect `mydomain.com/webmail` to `https://mydomain.com:8080/webmail`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <Location /webmail>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
      RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
    </Location>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The code worked but I want to make slight modification. I want to redirect `www.mydomain.com/webmail` to `https://mydomain.com:8080/webmail`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the rule to:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule . https://%2:8080%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```